# postgresql trigger on the insert table

Tags: postgresql

I created two tables
The first is

```
create SEQUENCE seg_cod start 1 increment 1 ;
create table value
(
id int primary key default nextval ( ' seg_cod ' ) ,
first varchar ( 10 ) not null
);
```

and the second is

```
create SEQUENCE seg_codRsult start 1 increment 1 ;
create table result
(
id int primary key default nextval ( ' seg_codRsult ' ) ,
primeiroR varchar ( 10 ) not null
);
```

I want to create a trigger that when inserting table in true value it insirar in Table 1 as a result the value in the table test me down if false insirar table result the value 0 ;

```
result    value
true       1
false      0
true       1
true       1
false      0
```

I know that to create a trigger must first create a function and then the trigger will call this function , because that's what I like sitting down ;

```
create ResulV function ( ) RETURNS TRIGGER AS $ $

begin

if new.primeiro = 'true ' then
insert into result values ​​( primeiroR + 1 ) ;
else
insert into result values ​​( primeiroR + 0 ) ;
end if ;

return null;
end ;
$ $ LANGUAGE plpgsql ;




triggerResulV create trigger on after insert value for each row execute
ResulV procedure ();
```

when I went to insert data into the table value it gave this error message

```
ERROR : " primeiror " column does not exist
LINE 1 : insert into results values ​​( primeiroR + 1 )
                                      ^
HINT : There is a " primeiror " column called , in the table "result " , but it can not be referenced from this part of the query .
QUERY : insert into results values ​​( primeiroR + 1 )
CONTEXT : PL / pgSQL resulv ( ) function in SQL command line 6
Error ********** **********

ERROR : " primeiror " column does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Hint : There is a " primeiror " column called , in the table "result " , but it can not be referenced from this part of the query .
Context : PL / pgSQL resulv ( ) function in SQL command line 6
```

need help

Comment: which version your are using because if am using your trigger it show syntax error

Comment: the version I'm using is 9.3

Comment: am also using 9.3 but your trigger query so syntax error for me

Comment: I already know it's a syntax error, but I would like to know how to fix

Comment: ok. when invoke the trigger? (which table is inserted). Which Table means trigger in invoke if one table is inserted. specify the table name

Comment: okay. when invoking the trigger? table value (which is inserted into the table table = result).

Comment: ok you want to check the result table `primeiroR ='true'` then insert another row in same table with `primeiroR +1` that right

Comment: The problem is that you have significant spaces disseminated everywhere in your identifiers. For example you should call your column `primeiror` not `" primeiror "`, same thing for your sequence names and table names.

Comment: Same thing for `new.primeiro = 'true '`, one might wonder what the space after `true` is doing there.

Comment: 'primeiro' this field in which table

Comment: Change all of your identifiers to lowercase snake_case and I'll gladly help you :)